# Loading External Website in Cordova Apps

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I am loading an external website in a cordova app through inappbrowser. However the external website is loaded only after a transition from the default "index.html" in the project structure. Is there a way to avoid this transition and directly load the external website after deviceready function ?

```
onDeviceReady:function() 

{        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

        navigator.splashscreen.hide();

        if (navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
            navigator.notification.alert('An internet connection is required to continue');
        } else {

            var ref = window.open('https://example.com/', '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no,zoom=no');
        }
    },
```

Currently the Press of a device backbutton  takes me to the empty index.html file which is not appealing. Changing the src to the external website in the config.xml doesn't help as the website is then loaded externally in the device browser and not within the mobile app.

Comment: Alternatively you can use iframe to load external website inside index.html.

Comment: @Avijit : Need to use InAppBrowser :(

Comment: Check this plugin might meet your requirement. https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem, did you finally find a solution?